# Webscraping information could be in 1 of 3 places on a page, not sure how to use an if statement to eliminate the nonetype results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The following code is scraping data from an amazon product page. I have since discovered that the data for the price could be in 1 of 3 places depending on the type of product and how the price has been added to the page. the 2 other CSS selectors are not present.

for the website `url = f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B083PHB6XX'` I am using `price = soup.find('span', {'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'}).text.strip()`

However, for the website `url = f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B089SQHDMR'` I need to use `price = soup.find('span', {'id':'priceblock_pospromoprice'}).text.strip()`

Finally, for the website `url = f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0813QVVSW'` I need to use `price = soup.find('span', {'class':'a-size-base a-color-price'}).text.strip()`

I think a solution to hand this is for each url, try to find `priceblock_ourprice` and if that fails, try to find `priceblock_pospromoprice` and if that fails, go on to find `a-size base a-color-price`. I am not able to understand how to put this into an if statement which will not stop when an element is not found.

My original code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"}
urls = [f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B083PHB6XX', f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B089SQHDMR', f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0813QVVSW']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    name = soup.find('span', {'id': 'productTitle'}).text.strip()
    price = soup.find('span', {'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'}).text.strip()

    print(name)
    print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were already on the right track with your thoughts. First check the existence of the element in the conditions and then set the value for the price.

```
if soup.find('span', {'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'}):
    price = soup.find('span', {'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'}).text.strip()
elif soup.find('span', {'id':'priceblock_pospromoprice'}):
    price = soup.find('span', {'id':'priceblock_pospromoprice'}).text.strip()
elif soup.find('span', {'class':'a-size-base a-color-price'}):
    price = soup.find('span', {'class':'a-size-base a-color-price'}).text.strip()
else:
    price = ''
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"}
urls = [f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B083PHB6XX', f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B089SQHDMR', f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0813QVVSW']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    name = soup.find('span', {'id': 'productTitle'}).text.strip()
    
    if soup.find('span', {'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'}):
        price = soup.find('span', {'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'}).text.strip()
    elif soup.find('span', {'id':'priceblock_pospromoprice'}):
        price = soup.find('span', {'id':'priceblock_pospromoprice'}).text.strip()
    elif soup.find('span', {'class':'a-size-base a-color-price'}):
        price = soup.find('span', {'class':'a-size-base a-color-price'}).text.strip()
    else:
        price = ''

    print(name)
    print(price)
```

#### Output

```
Boti 36475 Shark Hand Puppet Baby Shark with Sound Function and Speed Control, Approx. 27 x 21 x 14 cm, Soft Polyester, Battery Operated
£19.50
LEGO 71376 Super Mario Thwomp Drop Expansion Set
£34.99
LEGO 75286 Star Wars General Grievous’s Starfighter Set
£86.99
```